# Antd - how to set precision of a progress text

Tags: antd

I'm using the "Progress" component from Antd Design, but the text showing percent of progress is showing too many decimals (7.000000000000001%). Could anyone please help me adjust it?

I tried:
`precision={0}`
and
`step={0}`

but it doesn't work. Cannot find anything in Antd documents about it.

The code sample:

```
<Progress
  percent={totalLearned / 200 * 100}
  precision={1}
  strokeColor={{
    '0%': '#dddd1b',
    '200%': '#52c41a',
  }}
/>
```

Comment: Could you provide your current code? or share the working code in codesandbox/codepen etc

Comment: @DevThiman I have added the code to the answer. It's a very basic use case for the "Progress" bar from Antd. I just wonder why the precision wouldn't work. Thank you!!